# JOOQ Ordering using CASE expressions

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

I'm using **JOOQ** for half a year now and must say that it's quite superb :)

The problem I encountered is: I'm trying to generate **plain SQL query** containing `order by` clause with `case ... when` statements to achieve custom sorting order as described [in this part of JOOQ tutorial](http://www.jooq.org/doc/2.5/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/order-by-clause/#N109C1).

However, when I'm using [Field.sortAsc(Collection< T> sortList)](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.3.x/org/jooq/Field.html#sortAsc%28java.util.Collection%29) method and passing `Collection` of `String`s I get following `order by` clause in query:

```
order by 
    case `type` 
    when ? then ?
    when ? then ?
    when ? then ? 
    when ? then ? 
    when ? then ? end asc
```

Because I'm not using **JOOQ** for executing queries, I need to specify these values myself which is quite inconvenient.

Partial solution to this problem was to pass `Collection` of `Param<String>` values obtained from original values using [DSL.inline(T)](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.3.x/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#inline%28T%29) method. However, in that case placeholders still exist and `order by` clause in query looks like:

```
order by 
    case `type` 
    when 'type_a' then ?
    when 'type_b' then ?
    when 'type_c' then ? 
    when 'type_d' then ? 
    when null then ? end asc
```

Is this expected behaviour or this can be considered as bug and should be reported?

For now, I worked this problem around by using [Field.sort(Map sortMap)](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.3.x/org/jooq/Field.html#sort%28java.util.Map%29) method, passing `Map<Param<String>, Param<Integer>>` to it with incremented integer values. There is minor problem with this method as well, because it returns `SortField` instance which doesn't have methods like `asc()`, `desc()` or `sort(SortOrder)` so in order to sort with different orders this map should be regenerated.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: *"There is minor problem with this method as well, because it returns SortField instance which doesn't have methods like asc(), desc() or sort(SortOrder) so in order to sort with different orders this map should be regenerated."* - hmm, [`Field.sort(Map)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#sort%28java.util.Map%29) returns a `SortField`, which has `asc()`, `desc()` methods. You mean that calling them has no effect, maybe? Could you please show an example for that?

Comment: As per Javadoc http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.3.x/org/jooq/SortField.html `SortField` is an interface which doesn't have `asc()`, `desc()` or `sort(SortOrder)` methods... Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to extract *all* bind values from a query, use [`Query.getBindValues()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Query.html#getBindValues%28%29). The sort indirection values should be in there. See also the [relevant section of the manual](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/indexed-parameters/).

Note, it might be generally useful to generate "inline" sort indirection values instead of bind values to prevent this in the future. Execution-plan-wise, I don't think there will be any difference. I have registered [Issue #3147](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3147) for this.

Comment: Hmmm, didn't know about `Query.getBindValues()` - that provides new possibilities :) Thanks for your answer and for registering issue for my request!